# When using the top command on aws ec2, why are there processes which I've never installed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]

When I used my ubuntu in ec2, I saw the daemon processes which I've never installed.
As you can see, redis-server and mysqld whose user is 999 are not mine.

Why did this happen?
Is it related with virtualization of resource?

Comment: If you didn't deliberately install and start these services, then perhaps you've launched an EC2 instance from an AMI that includes Redis and MySQL. They are nothing to do with virtualization, per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened one of three ways, imo:

1) you spun up your ec2 instance using an AMI that had all of that already baked into the image, 
2) you, or someone else with legitimate access either installed it, or installed something else which then installed those items as part of the setup process
3) someone with illegitimate access installed it

Which base AMI do you pick when you first spun up the instance? And how many other people have access?

In answer to part of your question though - no, the virtualization does not install any/most of those processes: mysql or redis, in particular.

Comment: I picked [ Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-00edfb46b107f643c ] of free tier and only I use the instance.

Comment: doesn't look like that image would have contained any of that extra software, so someone - or some other program - must have installed them for you, perhaps as a dependency to something you are running on it at some point.

Comment: I finally figured it out. It was docker container which started these processes. I was so stupid.  Thank you for suggesting that kind of systematic approaches